# startActivity not always working on Android 7

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I am facing a weird situation that seems okay on Android < 8. I am starting any apps able to handle this intent:

```
val emailSelectorIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
emailSelectorIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.selector = emailSelectorIntent
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("testemail@yahoo.co.uk"))
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Testing")
Log.e(TAG, "Called 1")
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Called 2")
      startActivity(intent)
      Log.e(TAG, "Called 3")
} else {
      Log.e(TAG, "Called 4 - Error")
}
```

This is called from a button click in an Activity. It is working fine (tested on Android 6 and 7) but on Android 8, 9 I had to tap the button twice before the activity is started although Called 1, 2 and 3 are always printed for each clicks. Same code working perfectly on 6 & 7 but needs two clicks to work on Android > 7. Any obvious thing am doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm very strange. I tried your code and it worked on android 8

Comment: but i converted your code to java just..

Comment: @AbdulWaheed does it always work (shows) anytime you call the method?